# How can i put a border under background image?

Tags: html, css, border

I have a background image and a border around it, so i need to put that border under my background image like it displayed in my draft. [Draft image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOmHF.png)
Now i have something like this. [My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7MGM.png)
How can i fix it?
CSS

> .hero-image {
> position: relative;
> width: 100%;
> margin-left: 44px;
> max-width: 716px;
> height: 626px;
> background-image: url("/img/hero/hero-bg.jpg");
> background-repeat: no-repeat;
> background-position: -150px;
> background-clip: border-box;
> background-size: cover;
> border-bottom-right-radius: 140px;
> border-top-left-radius: 140px;
> }
> .hero-image::after {
> content: "";
> position: absolute;
> width: 716px;
> height: 626px;
> border: 2px solid #b0855b;
> box-sizing: border-box;
> border-bottom-right-radius: 140px;
> border-top-left-radius: 140px;
> transform: translate(35px, 33px);
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a z-index in the `:after` selector.

```
.hero-image::after {
   ...
   z-index: -1;
}
```

Code snippet [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9ca2odLe/4/).

Comment: It works! I never thought that z-index could be negative. So many things to learn! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try with "z-index" property.
Indicates the order of a positioned element and its descendants.
Example:

.hero-image { z-index: 1; }

.hero-image-2 { z-index: 0; }

Comment: Z-index was a first thing I tried, and unfortunately it still doesn't work. Could that problem is appearing because I using :after selector?